# dismiss viewcontroller from parents view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a parent `viewController` and a `childviewController` named `MyController`.
I would like to show the childview for some seconds and then dismiss it.
How do I dismiss the childs viewcontroller from the parents view controller ?

My code so far:

```
   let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle:  NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let vc : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyController") as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    <<wait for some seconds>>

    -->> dismissview from parents view ???
```

Comment: You can use `NSTimer` and schedule it.

Comment: I precised my question. The question is how do I dismiss it ?

Comment: if you use UIContainerView, show the view and hidden the view, its simple to use in storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dispatch_after`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after) with some time interval to delay the execution of the block:

```
let seconds: NSTimeInterval = 5.0
let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
  vc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

You can define it as a function in case you might need it somewhere else in your program:

```
func dispatch_async_main_queue(delay: NSTimeInterval, _ block: dispatch_block_t) {
  let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
  dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
}
```

--

```
dispatch_async_main_queue(5.0) {
  vc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will accept in 9mins, because i am stuck from upvoting :-)